# Thread to pick from db and to delete

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I am new to Threads. I want a thread to continuously look into my db and pic records according to a flag and another thread to delete the records once picked. How can i do this?
Can i implement two run methods in the same class? Please Help

```
public class QueManager implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                ResultSet rs = DBManager.select("select * from dbwhere READ_FLAG=0 ");
                int count = ResultProcessor.processResult(rs);
                if(count==0){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) { 
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {

            }
        }
    }

    public static void StartDemon(){
        QueManager manage = new QueManager();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(manage);
        t1.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to show what you have tried, explain why it is not working, and elaborate on your problems more.  As it stands this question does not meet SO.com standards

Comment: We'd need to know what language you're intending to write this program in as well.

Comment: @PWKad: i have added the code i tried.

Comment: @DanGrossman: i m using java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is wise to use separate classes for picking and deleting.

You can fire off similar to how you have it now:

```
 Thread t1 = new Thread(manage);
 Thread deleteThread = ... 
 t1.start();
 deleteThread.start();
```

Comment: can two threads use the same mysql connection object? Thanks for the suggestion. I will try this out.

Comment: You could do some simple connection pooling that would allow you to pass a connection from the pool to each thread.  Threads fire in their own process, so I don't think you'll have much luck using the same actual db connection from different threads.